# iOS error while calling web service, A server with the specified hostname could not be found

Tags: ios, api, hostname

Random error I get when I try to call api

Following is the snippet from error description.

> NSLocalizedDescription = "A server with the specified hostname could
>   not be found.";
>       NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1003 \"A server with the specified hostname could not be
>   found.\"

Error is very frequent & it goes away on next call. Can anyone help me to identify the root cause?

Comment: What API are you using? Provide the code, please.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of host not found.

```
kCFURLErrorCannotFindHost = -1003,
kCFURLErrorCannotFindHost
The connection failed because the host could not be found.
```

also see docs for more help from here 
[CFNetworkErrors help](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Reference/CFNetworkErrors/Reference/reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when server stops working frequently. So nothing wrong with your code, the problem is with server you are using for this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something wrong with DNS server, you need to ping the host and check whether the host is  reachable.